# Jasmine checking if variable is defined in method

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm new to jasmine. My Company is using jasmine 1.3.1

I am trying to test if a variable is defined in a method.  I keep coming back with a failure.

```
objectParentName.accessoriesSlider = {
modifyJSON: function(obj) {
        var contentLoadJSON = [];

        for (var property in obj) {
            objectParentName.accessoriesSlider.contentJSONTotal++
            contentLoadJSON.push(obj[property]);
        }

        contentLoadJSON = objectParentName.accessoriesSlider.sortJSON(contentLoadJSON, 'dateAdded', false);

        return contentLoadJSON;
    }
}
```

Here is jasmine for that method.

```
describe('Test "modifyJSON" function', function () {

    beforeEach(function() {
        spyOn(objectParentName.accessoriesSlider, 'modifyJSON');

        var contentLoadJSON = []; //forcibly add variable to see if that fixes issue
        objectParentName.accessoriesSlider.modifyJSON();
    });

    it('is defined as "modifyJSON"', function () {
        /**
         * objectParentName.accessoriesSlider.modifyJSON should be defined.
         */

        expect(objectParentName.accessoriesSlider.modifyJSON).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('and "modifyJSON" is a function', function () {
        /**
         * This should be a 'function'.
         */

        expect(objectParentName.accessoriesSlider.modifyJSON).toBeFunction();
    });

    describe('Test "contentLoadJSON" variable', function () {
        it('is defined', function () {
            expect(contentLoadJSON).toBeDefined();
        });

    });

});
```

I am getting this error

```
ReferenceError: contentLoadJSON is not defined
at .<anonymous> (http://localhost:8234/spec/jasmine_accessories_slider.js:300:24)
at jasmine.Block.execute (http://localhost:8234/?spec=accessories_slider.js:1164:19)
at jasmine.Queue.next_ (http://localhost:8234/?spec=accessories_slider.js:2196:33)
at jasmine.Queue.start (http://localhost:8234/?spec=accessories_slider.js:2149:10)
at jasmine.Spec.execute (http://localhost:8234/?spec=accessories_slider.js:2476:16)
at jasmine.Queue.next_ (http://localhost:8234/?spec=accessories_slider.js:2196:33)
at jasmine.Queue.start (http://localhost:8234/?spec=accessories_slider.js:2149:10)
at jasmine.Suite.execute (http://localhost:8234/?spec=accessories_slider.js:2621:16)
at jasmine.Queue.next_ (http://localhost:8234/?spec=accessories_slider.js:2196:33)
at jasmine.Queue.start (http://localhost:8234/?spec=accessories_slider.js:2149:10)
```

So, I have no idea why I am getting an error here.

Comment: `var contentLoadJSON = objectParentName.accessoriesSlider.modifyJSON();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The first problem* is that the variable `contentLoadJSON` is not defined in the scope of the function you are calling it from.

When you define a variable using `var`, it becomes a local variable, and is only accessible inside the scope of that function. In this case, the function it exists in is:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    spyOn(objectParentName.accessoriesSlider, 'modifyJSON');

    var contentLoadJSON = [];

    objectParentName.accessoriesSlider.modifyJSON();
});
```

The function you are getting the error in is a different `function() { ... }` that isn't nested in `beforeEach`. It is therefore can't see the local variable you defined.

One way to rectify this is by defining the variable in the scope of your test suite, instead of in the scope of the `beforeEach` function:

```
describe('Test "modifyJSON" function', function () {
    var contentLoadJSON; // Define it here

    beforeEach(function() {
        contentLoadJSON = []; // Assign it here
        // ... more code here ...
    }

    // ... more code here ...

    describe('Test "contentLoadJSON" variable', function () {
        it('is defined', function () {
            // Test contentLoadJSON here...
```

*The second problem* is that just because variables have the same name doesn't mean they are actually the same variable. They have to also be *in the same scope* for that to be true. `var contentLoadJSON` inside `modifyJSON` is actually a totally different variable than the `var contentLoadJSON` you are defining in `beforeEach` in your test suite.

When you call the function under test, you are not assigning its result to the variable you are trying to test. In fact, you are actually throwing away the result immediately after you call the function.

To fix this, change:

```
var contentLoadJSON = [];
objectParentName.accessoriesSlider.modifyJSON();
// Note that contentLoadJSON still equals [] at this point.
// The return of the function call is getting thrown away,
// because you don't assign it to a variable
```

To:

```
var contentLoadJSON = objectParentName.accessoriesSlider.modifyJSON();
```

*The third problem* is that `expect(someVariable).toBeDefined();` might not do what you are expecting it to do. It doesn't check that the variable is "in scope". It checks that the value `someVariable` is not equal to the value `undefined`. Unless your function might sometimes return `undefined`, then this particular test isn't very important and will probably never fail.

It may be better to check that the result is "truthy" (`expect(contentLoadJSON).toBeTruthy()`). It might even make sense to just check that it is equal to the value you'd expect for the given data/input.